# How do I retrieve all of my repo deploy keys from github?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to add the ssh key from a web server to pull a repo from my github account. When I try to add the ssh key, github' errors says it's already been added. It turns out, I already used this web server's ssh key for a project's deploy keys. The problem is, I can't remember which repo uses that deploy key.

Is there a fast way to display all of my deploy keys from the api?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look possible to do programmatically from the api because there's no way to list private repos. I manually fixed it by entering some suspected repos into this URL:
https://github.com/username/reponame/settings/keys